# Google play console not detecting my SDK version correctly in bundles from react native expo

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, expo, google-play-console

I'm new to google play console so I'm not sure about what is happening. When I try to upload my bundle it just says I have an API versión of 30 and that I need to have at least 31 but my build has an SDK of 44. I've tried to downgrade the SDK from 44 to 31, tried to build it with "expo build:android" and with "eas build --platform android", nothing changed... Am I missing some config in the code or is it something else?

[Here an image of the build from the expo.dev webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH67V.png)

[Here the message i recive when i try to upload the bundle to GooglePlay Console."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vww8b.png)

The message in English says: "Currently, your app's target API level is 30, but it must be at least 31 to ensure it compiles with the latest APIs, which provide optimal security and performance. Change your application's target API level to level 31 or higher. More information

And the "More information" link: https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

I ended up triying the expo-build-properties but didn't even worked...

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "minSdkVersion": 31,
        "compileSdkVersion": 31,
        "targetSdkVersion": 31,
        "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
      },
      "ios": {
        "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define this :

```
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
```

Comment: Where? I guess that's inside a manifest file, but isn't it automatic with react native expo?

Comment: I am using, React Native CLI, not sure about expo.

Comment: I've been searching about compileSdkVersion and all that... I only found the "expo-build-properties" plugin and it didn't change anything to be honest.

Comment: Did you do it like this ->https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/ , or try upgrading your expo.